# Creating a proxy using sockets

Tags: sockets, delphi, proxy

I tried to write a proxy which passes traffic from 127.0.0.1:80 to 192.168.69.1:80 . This is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s :=  Socket.ReceiveText;

  clientsocket1.Open;
  clientsocket1.Socket.SendText(s);
  s := clientsocket1.Socket.ReceiveText;

  socket.SendText(s);
  socket.Close;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientSocket1.Host := '192.168.69.1';
  ClientSocket1.Port := 80;
  ClientSocket1.ClientType := ctBlocking;
  ClientSocket1.Active := true;

  ServerSocket1.OnClientRead := ServerSocket1ClientRead;
  ServerSocket1.Port := 80;
  ServerSocket1.Active := true;
end;
```

The ServerSocket part works. I receive the HTTP requests, and I could send stuff back to the browser. However, the ClientSocket part fails. I receive 1 HTML page, and every further request ends in an empty string (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE).

What am I doing wrong?

For this small tool, I only want to use the basic components from Delphi 6, without third party VCLs.

Comment: Delphi ships with Indy preinstalled, which has a `TIdMappedPortTCP` component that does exactly what you are attempting.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for the hint. Alas, I am currently using Delphi 6 Personal at home. (Yes, that's very cheap...) Of course I can download and install Indy, but I think a proxy is just a 10-lines-code using sockets - or are there cases which require a more complex logic?

Comment: There are cases that require more complex logic.

Answer (score 2):

This is the wrong way to implement a passthrough proxy with `TServerSocket`.

The `OnClientRead` event is triggered every time `TServerSocket` receives raw data from the web browser.  DO NOT connect and disconnect your `TClientSocket` on every block of data received.  You should be connecting your `TClientSocket` in the server's `OnClientConnect` event instead, close that connection in the server's `OnClientDisconnect` event, and use `ReceiveBuf()`/`SendBuf()` in the `OnClientRead` event instead of `ReceiveText()`/`SendText()`.

You also need to take into account that it may take multiple `OnRead` events before the web server has any data to send back.  Use the `TClientSocket` in non-blocking mode with its own `OnRead` event handler to send data from the web server to the web browser.

You also have to take into account that in non-blocking mode, `SendBuf()` can fail with a `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error.  If that happens, you have to cache the data you are currently sending and wait for the socket's `OnWrite` event to be called before you can send data to that socket again.

You also need to take onto account that the web browser can, and likely will, create multiple connections to your proxy.  Your proxy will thus need multiple `TClientSocket` connections, one for each web browser connection.

Try something more like this instead, at a bare minimum (implementing a *proper* HTTP proxy requires even more logic than this):

```
type
  TMyBuffer = class(TMemoryStream)
  private
    FSocket: TCustomWinSocket;
  public
    constructor Create(ASocket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure Send(Data: Pointer; DataLen: Integer);
    procedure Flush;
  end;

  TMyServerSocketData = class;
  TMyClientSocket = class(TClientSocket)
  private
    FBuffer: TMyBuffer;
    FServerSocketData: TMyServerSocketData;
  protected
    procedure Event(Socket: TCustomWinSocket; SocketEvent: TSocketEvent); override;
    procedure Error(Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent; var ErrorCode: Integer); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AServerSocketData: TMyServerSocketData); reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Send(Data: Pointer; DataLen: Integer);
    property ServerSocketData: TMyServerSocketData read FServerSocketData;
  end;

  TMyServerSocketData = class
  private
    FBuffer: TMyBuffer;
    FClientSocket: TMyClientSocket;
    FServerSocket: TCustomWinSocket;
  public
    constructor Create(AServerSocket: TCustomWinSocket);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Send(Data: Pointer; DataLen: Integer);
    procedure FlushBuffer;
    property ClientSocket: TMyClientSocket read FClientSocket;
    property ServerSocket: TCustomWinSocket read FServerSocket;
  end;

constructor TMyBuffer.Create(ASocket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FSocket := ASocket;
end;

procedure TMyBuffer.Send(Data: Pointer; DataLen: Integer);
var
  PData: PByte;
begin
  PData := PByte(Data);
  if Self.Size = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      NumSent := FSocket.SendBuf(PData^, DataLen);
      if NumSent < 1 then Break;
      Inc(PData, NumSent);
      Dec(DataLen, NumSent);
    until DataLen = 0;
  end;
  if DataLen > 0 then
  begin
    Self.Seek(0, soEnd);
    Self.WriteBuffer(PData^, DataLen);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyBuffer.Flush;
var
  PData: PByte;
  DataLen, NumSent: Integer;
begin
  if Self.Size = 0 then Exit;
  Self.Position := 0;
  PData := PByte(Self.Memory);
  DataLen := Self.Size;
  repeat
    NumSent := FSocket.SendBuf(PData^, DataLen);
    if NumSent < 1 then Break;
    Inc(PData, NumSent);
    Dec(DataLen, NumSent);
    Self.Seek(NumSent, soCurrent);
  until DataLen = 0;
  if Self.Position = 0 then Exit;
  if Self.Position = Self.Size then
    Self.Clear
  else begin
    Move(PData, Self.Memory, DataLen);
    Self.Size := DataLen;
  end;
end;

constructor TMyClientSocket.Create(AServerSocketData: TMyServerSocketData);
begin
  inherited Create(nil);
  ClientType := ctNonBlocking;
  FBuffer := TMyBuffer.Create(Socket);
  FServerSocketData := AServerSocketData;
end;

destructor TMyClientSocket.Destroy;
begin
  FBuffer.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyClientSocket.Send(Data: Pointer; DataLen: Integer);
begin
  FBuffer.Send(Data, DataLen);
end;

procedure TMyClientSocket.Event(Socket: TCustomWinSocket; SocketEvent: TSocketEvent);
var
  Buf: array[0..1023] of byte;
  BufLen, NumSent: Integer;
  PBuf: PByte;
begin
  case SocketEvent of
    seRead:
    begin
      if not FServerSocketData.ServerSocket.Connected then Exit;
      BufLen := Socket.ReceiveBuf(Buf[0], SizeOf(Buf));
      if BufLen > 0 then
        FServerSocketData.Send(@Buf[0], BufLen);
    end;
    seWrite:
      FBuffer.Flush;
  else
    inherited;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyClientSocket.Error(Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent; var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
  FServerSocketData.ServerSocket.Close;
  inherited;
end;

constructor TMyServerSocketData.Create(AServerSocket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FBuffer := TMyBuffer.Create(AServerSocket);
  FClientSocket := TMyClientSocket.Create(Self);
  FServerSocket := AServerSocket;
end;

destructor TMyServerSocketData.Destroy;
begin
  FBuffer.Free;
  FClientSocket.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyServerSocketData.Send(Data: Pointer; DataLen: Integer);
begin
  FBuffer.Send(Data, DataLen);
end;

procedure TMyServerSocketData.FlushBuffer;
begin
  FBuffer.Flush;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ServerSocket1.OnClientConnect := ServerSocket1ClientConnect;
  ServerSocket1.OnClientDisconnect := ServerSocket1ClientDisconnect;
  ServerSocket1.OnClientRead := ServerSocket1ClientRead;
  ServerSocket1.Port := 80;
  ServerSocket1.ServerType := stNonBlocking;
  ServerSocket1.Active := true;
end;

Procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  Data: TMyServerSocketData;
begin
  Data := TMyServerSocketData.Create(Socket);
  try
    Data.ClientSocket.Host := '192.168.69.1';
    Data.ClientSocket.Port := 80;
    Data.ClientSocket.Open;
  except
    Data.Free;
    raise;
  end;
  Socket.Data := Data;
end;

Procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  TMyServerSocketData(Socket.Data).Free;
end;

Procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  ClientSocket: TMyClientSocket;
  Buf: array[0..1023] of byte;
  BufLen: Integer;
begin
  ClientSocket := TMyServerSocketData(Socket.Data).ClientSocket;
  if not ClientSocket.Socket.Connected then Exit;
  BufLen := Socket.ReceiveBuf(Buf[0], SizeOf(Buf));
  if BufLen > 0 then
    ClientSocket.Send(@Buf[0], BufLen);
end;

Procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientWrite(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  TMyServerSocketData(Socket.Data).FlushBuffer;
end;
```

With that said, you really should reconsider using third-party components.  Indy ships preinstalled with Delhi and has a `TIdMappedPortTCP` component that does exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  Indy 9 and 10 also have a `TIdHTTPProxyServer` component (Delphi 6 shipped with Indy 8, but newer versions of Indy still support Delphi 6).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Alas, this code doesn't seem to work correctly. I assume there are deadlocks because HTML + pictures are loaded at the same time. So I installed Indy now. Do you have an example of a simple proxy using `TIdHTTPProxyServer `? Surprisingly, I couldn't find helpful resources using Google. Btw, using these 2 options (`TIdMappedPortTCP`, or `TIdHTTPProxyServer`), is it possible that the HTTP request header can be modified before it is forwarded? -- this would be important for me

Comment: There is no deadlock in the code I gave you. When a browser requests HTML ad its pictures, they will either be downloaded in a serial manner over a single connection, or they will be downloaded using separate connections in parallel. Either way, I did warn that what I provided was an *incomplete* implementation. I have updated it now with some additional logic to handle the case when outgoing data needs to be cached and retried in the `OnWrite` event. Behind that, you should read RFC 2616 for how to implement a proper HTTP proxy.

Comment: `TIdMappedPortTCP` is not a good choice for implementing an HTTP proxy. It would require a lot of manual work to implement HTTP proxying with it, as you would have to implement your own HTTP parser on top of it. That is why Indy has a separate `TIdHTTPProxyServer` component, which can modify HTTP headers and data, yes. It has `OnHTTPBeforeCommand`, `OnHTTPDocument`, and `OnHTTPResponse` events for that purpose.